# How can I see code for nib/xib files?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, macos, xib

Is it possible for us to see the source code generated behind the out of xib/nib files (I know they are xml files)?
I heard about NIBTOOL but I believe it is no longer available or replaced by some other tool which I cannot find. Does anyone know about it?

Thank you very much for responses.

Answer (score 6):

Nitish edited answer is : Just right click on nib file and Open As Source Code